# Localization in CaptchaValidation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, localization, attributes, captcha

I have a Register action in my AspNet Mvc application and it has a validation attribute 
`[CaptchaValidation("Captcha", "captchaValidateId", "errorMessage")]`

Now I need a localization via resources, but this attribute accepts only string as `errorMessage` param, so I made my own `LocalizedCaptchaValidationAttribute`:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = false)]
public class LocalizedCaptchaValidationAttribute :
    BotDetect.Web.Mvc.CaptchaValidationAttribute
{
    public LocalizedCaptchaValidationAttribute(string inputfield, string captchaId)
        : base(inputfield, captchaId, AccountRes.InvalidCapcha)
    {
    }
}
```

But there is a problem. Constructor called only on first Register action call. So, after language changing error message still the same.

For example:
Open Chinese version of the page, input incorrect captcha, submit, get

> "Invalid capcha _ch" error. Then switch to English, input incorrect
>   capcha, submit, get "Invalid capcha _ch" error instead of "Invalid
>   capcha _en".

How to solve this?

P.S. Localization works via language codes in `MapRoute` (example: /en/Account/Register) and setting `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture` and `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture`.

Comment: The localization via language codes works for other pages? (is the problem only in captcha?)

Comment: All fine for now. Problem in localization of strings, that passed in attributes.

Comment: Have you found the solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

As you said  "Constructor called only on first Register action call" , so attribute didn't accept localize Resource. 
However, you can check the ModelState for "Captcha" error and change it ie.

```
if (!ModelState.IsValid){
   if (ModelState["Captcha"] != null)
   {
      ModelState["Captcha"].Errors.RemoveAt(0);
      ModelState.AddModelError("Captcha",Resources.ErrorMessages.CaptchaCodeError);
   }    
   return View(model);
}
```